# Sorted in order of appearance

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to describe when something is sorted in "order of appearance"?

Bibliographies are often sorted like this. Names of actors/actresses in a movie sometimes are, too.

This is in contrast to how an index is usually sorted [ie alphabetically].

As an example, I might say:

> The definitions below are given in _ order.
>
> sorted: organized, arranged
>
> appearance: the act of becoming visible
>
> bibliography: a list of books referred to in a scholarly work
>
> alphabetically: ordering where strings are placed in order based on the position of characters in the conventional ordering of an alphabet

Comment: "Order of appearance" has about 3.3m Google hits, I would feel comfortable assuming that's the de facto standard.

Comment: (Not single words) classified by order of appearance, listed in the order of their occurence, sorted  in the order in which they appear in the document,

Comment: Isn't this simply "not sorted"?

Comment: I kinda get this vision of a manager handing his secretary a stack of index cards and saying, "Here, sort these cards in order of appearance."

Comment: (Arguably something ordered by appearance is not an "index" but rather a "table of contents".)

Comment: Given the number of movies that list "cast, in order of appearance", I suspected there isn't a shorter phrase.

Comment: Certainly "in order of appearance" is a fine phrase. And its definition is common knowledge. I was just hoping for a one-word version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to look for some examples; here are some from the "[ShareLaTeX knowledge base](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Main_Page)." Often there are index numbers in bibliographies like this; in that case, you could say it is "**in numeric order**." (the term is used this way here: [Biblatex bibliography styles](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Biblatex_bibliography_styles), and here: [Tips on Writing a Thesis in LaTeX](http://www.khirevich.com/latex/bibliography/)) In fact, since you did not use any kind of in-line citations connecting your definitions to the previous occurrences of the word, it took me a minute or two to realize what you were doing in your question.

The default behavior listed on [this page](http://Bibliography%20management%20in%20LaTeX) for the "none" sorting option describes this by saying "entries are processed **in citation order**." 
That term is also used in this question: [Sort thebibliography by citation order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17354/sort-thebibliography-by-citation-order). I don't know if it's used outside of the TeX community.

As others have mentioned, it's common to use a phrase to describe this, even when in explicit contrast with "alphabetic" (Example: "how could Mellel know if the order should be alphabetic or by order of occurrence?" found on a [forum about Mellel](http://forum.mellel.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=2366)) and an extra word or two seems in my opinion a small price to pay for increased clarity.

---

Example of how your question could be written if the definitions were listed in numerical order:

> Is there a single word to describe when something is sorted<sup>1</sup> in "order
>   of appearance"<sup>2</sup>?
>
> Bibliographies<sup>3</sup> are often sorted like this. Names of actors/actresses
>   in a movie sometimes are, too.
>
> This is in contrast to how an index is usually sorted [ie
>   alphabetically<sup>4</sup>].
>
> As an example, I might say:
>
> > The definitions below are given in numerical order.
> >
> > 1. sorted: organized, arranged
> > 2. appearance: the act of becoming visible
> > 3. bibliography: a list of books referred to in a scholarly work
> > 4. alphabetically: ordering where strings are placed in order based on
> >        the position of characters in the conventional ordering of an alphabet

Comment: I really like this answer. I've also heard "in reference order" for bibliographies but wasn't sure if that was commonly used or not.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it would be more commonly worded as "*listed* in order of appearance", rather than "sorted".

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=listed%20in%20order%20of%20appearance%2Csorted%20in%20order%20of%20appearance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clisted%20in%20order%20of%20appearance%3B%2Cc0) seems to agree. "Sorted in order of appearance" is not found.

But I'm not aware of a single word for this kind of sorting.

Answer (score 2):

If you treat appearances as time dependent events, you are listing the things according to their associated event times.

This implies the order is ***chronological***.

> : arranged in the order that things happened or came to be
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chronological)</sub>

However, I would find it strange for someone to describe it that way. *Order of appearance* seems clear and well understood.

> If a film has an ensemble cast with no clear lead role, it is traditional to bill the participants alphabetically or *in the order of their on-screen appearance*.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billing_(filmmaking))</sub>

Comment: If I were told a certain bibliography was sorted in "chronological order," I'd expect the entries to be arranged based on the dates when the cited documents were published.

Comment: The chronology of course depends on the point of reference. Mysteries of the space-time continuum.